# How to stop rediffmail from removing hashes form hyperlinks

Tags: email, hash, hyperlink

I'm working on an application that sends weekly newsletter emails to registered members. But in rediffmail, the hyperlinks to my webiste are by default modified and the hashes (#) are removed which in turn resulting in a 404 error on my site. [If the users clicks on that link in rediffmail] Please help me how to stop rediffmail from removing hashes from the link urls.